# How to redirect from sub category to a main category using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect URLs using .htaccess.
Now the URLs are

```
example.com/p/s/red.html
example.com/p/s/blue.html
example.com/p/s/green.html
example.com/p/s/yellow.html
```

etc.
I like to remove 's' from the URL and move pages directly under the 'p' category.

```
example.com/p/red.html
example.com/p/blue.html
example.com/p/green.html
example.com/p/yellow.html
```

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^p/s/(.*)$ /p/$1
```

it is not working.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service, we expect you to make an effort yourself first. Show us what you tried, and give us a proper problem description along with it.

Comment: Sorry for not including my efforts to solve the issue. I have added what I have done to solve the issue.

Comment: That should work, but so far it would be an internal rewrite only. If you want an external redirect, you need to use the `R` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer.

First I tried

```
RewriteRule ^p/s/(.*)$ /p/$1
```

it is not working. then I tried

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)/(.*) /p/$2 [R=301,L]
```

it worked.

Comment: There should be no need to use `(.*)`, instead of matching `s` directly. And if you could have URLs such as `example.com/p/x/red.html` or `example.com/p/foo/red.html` that you don’t want to be rewritten, this would actually be to broad.